# Convert PowerShell to C#

Tags: c#, powershell, function, microsoft-graph-api

I have a function in PowerShell that I am using to get access token to AAD and then get expiration dates for client secrets. I am not very well versed in C# and would like to convert this PowerShell to C#. Is there a way to do this using a VS Code plugin, etc.??

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
function Get-GraphAccessToken
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param (
        [string]$tenantID, 
        [string]$clientID, 
        [string]$clientSecret
    )

    process
    {
        if($tenantID.Length -eq 0 -or
            $clientID.Length -eq 0 -or
            $clientSecret.Length -eq 0)
        {
            Write-Error "Invalid input received. Please specify all parameters in order to use this function."
            return $null
        }

        $tokenAuthURI = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($tenantID)/oauth2/v2.0/token"

        Write-Debug "Using '$($tokenAuthURI)' as token authentication endpoint."
        #
        # Construct the request body
        #
        $requestBody = "grant_type=client_credentials" + 
                        "&client_id=$($clientID)" + 
                        "&client_secret="+ ([System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($clientSecret)) + 
                        "&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fcalendarmanagement.site.com" +  
                        "&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"

        $RequestedDate = Get-Date

        Write-Debug "Passing $($requestBody) to authentication endpoint."
        #
        # POST the request body to the token URI
        #
        $tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $tokenAuthURI -body $requestBody -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

        Write-Debug "Response retrieved from token endpoint with $($tokenResponse.Length) bytes length."
        
        #
        # Get token from the tokenResponse
        #
        $SecureAccessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
        $AccessTokenCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('access_token', $SecureAccessToken) #[pscredential]::new('access_token', $SecureAccessToken )

        #
        # Construct 'AccessToken' object
        #
        @{
            Application = $Application
            AccessTokenCredential = $AccessTokenCredential
            RequestedDate = $RequestedDate
            Response = $tokenResponse | Select-Object -property * -ExcludeProperty access_token, refresh_token
            LastRequestDate = $RequestedDate
            Session = $Session
            GUID = [guid]::NewGuid()
        }
    }
}

$creds = Get-GraphAccessToken -tenantID $tenant_id -clientID $aad_client_id -clientSecret $aad_client_secret
    $access_token = $creds.AccessTokenCredential.GetNetworkCredential().password

    Query_Applications -accessToken $creds -app_id $aad_client_id -logJSON

    Connect-MsolService -AzureEnvironment AzureCloud -MsGraphAccessToken $access_token

    $expiration_dates = (Get-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $spo_client_id -ReturnKeyValues $true).EndDate | select
    $exp_date = $expiration_dates[$expiration_dates.Count-1]

    Write-Host "Current expiration date is $($exp_date.ToShortDateString())"

    if($exp_date -lt $today){
        Write-Host "Client credentials have expired." -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "Client credentials are still valid" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
```

Comment: This is not a free script-translation service; please be specific about what you've tried, where you got stuck and what you need help with :)

Comment: Hi @MathiasR.Jessen! I understand and thanks for the response. I have looked into multiple ways to do this. One is using the System.Management,Automation and calling the PS command, but that only seems to be for some one liners. It seems for larger scripts with functions, etc. the other option is importing a PS1 file. Is one method preferably better than the other? Just look for guidance on the best approach. Thanks

Comment: What you're describing here (hosting PowerShell runtime in your C# app) is very different from _translating_ the code to C# - but both are completely valid approaches. If you want to host PowerShell in C# and execute a script you've already written, like here, then using the API to execute a single script file (ie. a `*.ps1` file) is indeed going to be much simpler than manually adding all the individual statements.